# start-bitstransfer : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: windows, powershell

In powershell I am unable to copy files using BITS Transfer that are in use by other processes (a service in my case).

```
Start-BitsTransfer -Source "E:/path1/dir1/file1.txt" -Destination
```

produces

> start-bitstransfer : The process cannot access the file because it is
>   being used by another process.

However, Copy-Item has no such issue. Unfortunately I can't use Copy-Item because it has no option to go into low priority / background mode and it may therefore put too much strain on the servers that I'm downloading from.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using **start /low xcopy**

https://searchenterprisedesktop.techtarget.com/answer/Copying-Windows-Explorer-files-without-slowing-down-a-system

Comment: Hi Dylan - I have just started reading about this command - do you know if the priority will be 'transferred' over to the remote hosts that I am downloading the files from? Furthermore - do you now if the same also happens with the /J switch (unbuffered I/O)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using in Asynchronous mode:

```
$Job = Start-BitsTransfer -Source https://Server1.TrustedDomain.com/File1.zip `
       -Destination d:\temp\downloads\ -Asynchronous

while (($Job.JobState -eq "Transferring") -or ($Job.JobState -eq "Connecting")) `
       { sleep 5;} # Poll for status, sleep for 5 seconds, or perform an action.

Switch($Job.JobState)
{
    "Transferred" {Complete-BitsTransfer -BitsJob $Job}
    "Error" {$Job | Format-List } # List the errors.
    default {"Other action"} #  Perform corrective action.
}
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/bits/using-windows-powershell-to-create-bits-transfer-jobs

I was getting the same error copying from PC to network drive over VPN, searching for hooks using the file name I was trying to copy with Process Monitor didn't return anything.  I'd say there's some threading shenanigans somewhere.  Async BitsTransfer in more of a pain but is pretty resilient to errors.

Depending on how you invoke bittransfer you may need to use the [Complete-BitsTransfer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitstransfer/complete-bitstransfer?view=win10-ps) command